# Apache Camel blocking on multicast

Tags: jboss, jms, apache-camel, multicast

I have an application that consists of many modules deployed in several JBoss instances. Those modules broadcast their version numbers via JMS to each other.

It works in the following way. Each module periodically broadcasts its versions like this:

```
camelTemplate.asyncSendBody(moduleVersionsOutputChannel, new ArrayList<>(moduleVersions));
```

Here's the definition of `moduleVersionsOutputChannel`:

```
<endpoint id="moduleVersionsOutputChannel" uri="direct:module.versions.output.channel"/>
```

Then there's a route that consumes messages from `moduleVersionsOutputChannel` (referred as `source` below) and posts the messages into topics:

```
from(source).multicast()
        .parallelProcessing().timeout(moduleVersionsMonitoringConfig.getMulticastTimeout())
        .to(moduleVersionsMonitoringConfig.getChannels())
        .id(moduleVersionsService.getCurrentModuleId() + "-outbound");
```

At the beginning everything works fine, but after some time (hours or days) the threads that do multicast are blocked. I observe blocks at 2 different points.

The first block happens in the thread where `asyncSendBody` is called:

```
"moduleVersionsBroadcastScheduler-1@57542" prio=5 tid=0x423 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:994)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
      at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:236)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:328)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:214)
      at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
      at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:73)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:378)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:346)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:242)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:346)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:184)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:137)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate$14.call(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:621)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2025)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
      at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:132)
      at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.asyncSendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:626)
      at ...
```

Another time the execution blocks at the later point when it actually tries to post a message to JMS topics:

```
"Camel (moduleVersionsContext) thread #1044 - Multicast@52031" daemon prio=5 tid=0xa16 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:994)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
      at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:472)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerCreditsImpl.acquireCredits(ClientProducerCreditsImpl.java:90)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:307)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:288)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:140)
      at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.doSend(HornetQMessageProducer.java:438)
      at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:205)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:589)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSend(JmsConfiguration.java:336)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:275)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:217)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:231)
      at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:228)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:431)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:385)
      at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:153)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)
      at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
      at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:712)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:83)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:293)
      at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:278)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can you tell me whether I have a bug in my Camel configuration or it's a known Camel issue and there's some workaround?

My environment:

- Apache Camel 2.12.3
- JBoss 6.1 EAP
- OpenJDK 1.7.0_55
- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.  Try to configure the cxf producer endpoint to synchronous.  This resolved my issue

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Intermittent-STUCK-threads-in-Weblogic-Server-due-to-camel-application-td5750624.html

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, however I'm not using any cxf endpoints here.